# arrayWithArray not resetting values

Tags: objective-c

I am currently working on a tile-based-game with numbers in Xcode. In my method called checkGameOver, every tile is moved around to every combination possible, and checked if they are valid moved. However, since that method changes the mutable array called 'values',and I thought the easiest way to avoid this would be to just make a copy of 'values', store it into 'originalValues' and then restore it afterwards. However, it does seem like it actually doesn't change back. I tried using copy also. I don't understand why it doesn't work. Could it be that checkGameOver is really because of the thousands of calculations, and it isn't finished until after the values are changed back?

```
    NSArray *originalValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:values];
    [self checkGameOver];
    values = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:originalValues];
```

Explanation: I have array A (values), I create a duplicate of that array, B (originalValues). I make changes on A, but the changes are reflected in B as well.

Comment: What's changing? Your issue isn't clear. Are the individual values changing?

Comment: checkGameOver-method is changing 'value'(the array). I try to revert these changes to what they used to be.

Comment: *Why* does that method change it?  Fix it so it doesn't change the array, using another data store if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a deep copy of an `NSArray`, you need to use archiving. See the following example:

```
NSMutableArray *values = [@[@"one", @"two"] mutableCopy];
NSData *originalValues = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:values];

[values replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"something"];
NSLog(@"changed: %@", values);
values = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:originalValues];
NSLog(@"restored: %@", values);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved it. Great:) Wish I understood why though.

Comment: An array stores pointers to objects. When you add objects to an array, you just add their memory addresses. Maybe this will help you understand the idea of a deep copy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy